# Jetpack keeps loading forever on one of my blogs

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

Jetpack keeps loading forever on one of my blogs as shown below:

[image]

It works fine on another blog, same setting but not sure what is going wrong with this blog, anyone faced this issue before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a deeper look to find out why the stats are not matching with the Audit log. The site is visible only to registered users of this network and this is giving wordpress and jetpack hard time to get the actual number of views.

The only solution for that is to change the visibility permission to 'Allow search engines to index this site'.